# Can't figure out the syntax for calling a stored procedure with parameters for edge-sql

Tags: sql-server, edge.js

I'm not sure how to format the string request to edge-sql in order to execute a stored procedure that requires parameters. If I change the stored procedure to not use parameters and just send `exec sp_III_UpdateOperMgr` it executes properly.

Below is the syntax I am using in edge-sql that returns the error

> "Could not find stored procedure 'sp_III_UpdateOperMgr 
>   @quoteNumber,@poNumber'."

```
var updateOpMgrSql  = edge.func('sql',{
    connectionString: GM_CONNECTION_STRING,
    source:function () {
        /*
         exec sp_III_UpdateOperMgr  @quoteNumber,@poNumber
         */
    },
});
```

Below is the syntax used in MS SQL Server Management Studio that executes properly

`exec sp_III_UpdateOperMgr @quoteNumber='121715JM-1',@innovationJobNumber='999999'`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the parameters in the stored procedure itself are @quoteNumber and @poNumber can you try:

```
var updateOpMgrSql  = edge.func('sql',{
connectionString: GM_CONNECTION_STRING,
source:function () {
    /*
     exec sp_III_UpdateOperMgr  @quoteNumber=@quoteNumberParam,@poNumber=@poNumberParam
     */
},
});
```

Then call the updateOpMgrSql function with:

```
updateOpMgrSql({ quoteNumberParam: 10, poNumberParam: 15 }, function (error, result) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Looks like it was added in [here](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge-sql/commit/1ddb418a77e391673a5e3d97ee7769a2fba3e73e) in 2013. Also the procedure works if It doesn't require parameters.

Comment: So how are you calling updateOpMgrSql? Something like `updateOpMgrSql({ quoteNumber: 10, poNumber: 15 }...`?

Comment: Yes.```function updateOpmgr(){
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    updateOpMgrSql({quoteNumber:'121715JM-1',poNumber:'999999'}, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            winston.log('error', err);
            return deferred.reject(err)
        }
        deferred.resolve(true);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it there is a better way but I ended up editing the C sharp code being used by the JavaScript.I had to add a split on the first empty space after the SP name then take the first item in the array which would be the actual name of the procedure.

Before it was including the all the parameters passed when needing the SP name only

`commandString.Substring(5).TrimEnd()`

After I get the first item in the array by splitting the string on the first white space

`commandString.Substring(5).Split(' ')[0].TrimEnd()`

`async Task<object> ExecuteStoredProcedure(
        string connectionString,
        string commandString,
        IDictionary<string, object> parameters)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            var spName = commandString.Substring(5).Split(' ')[0].TrimEnd();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(spName, connection)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            };
            using (command)
            {
                return await this.ExecuteQuery(parameters, command, connection);
            }
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work for me. This syntax works as well. You don't have to write the parameters in the sql code. You only need to include them in the javascript parameters as you will see below. Here is my stored procedure:

```
create procedure [dbo].[p_Test]
    @p nvarchar(max) = null
as
begin 
    select * from [registration].[User] 
    where UserName = @p
end
```

You can swap out the table and parameter in the example above to suit your particular database.
Here is my edge code:

```
var getUser = edge.func('sql', function () {
    /*
    exec [dbo].[p_Test] 
    */
});

getUser({p:'SomeUserName'}, function (error, result) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(result);
});
```